# Woocommerce order->get_data() throws PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, return

I have a function running which first checks to the see if the post type is 'shop_order' and if it's not then the function shouldn't be run. I'm using the `return;` to end it but when I try adding a new post in the 'product' post type i get the following error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_data() on boolean in..
```

Why is it saying the function `get_data()` is uncaught? This code shouldn't run to this point if the `post_type` is not `shop_order`. I've even printed out $post_type which returns `product`.

```
function woocommerce_process_shop_order ( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    if (isset($post->post_status) && 'auto-draft' == $post->post_status) {
      return;
    }
        // Autosave, do nothing
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }
        // AJAX? Not used here
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
        return;
    }
        // Check user permissions
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
          return;
    }

    // don't run the echo if the function is called for saving revision.
    if ( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) {
       return;
    }

        $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    error_log( print_r( $post_type, true ) );

   // terminate early if post type is not 'post' and if we are updating post object and not creating it.
   if ( "shop_order" != $post_type && !$update ) {
       return;
       error_log( print_r( 'not shop order', true ) );
   }

  $is_new = $post->post_date === $post->post_modified;

  if ( $is_new ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );
    $order_data = $order->get_data();

  }
}
```

Comment: Your error message says that you are calling get_data() on a boolean data type. See docu of the function 'wc_get_order': https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_order.html The order cannot be found, false is returned (which is boolean). You need to check, if $order is of WC_Order data type, before you call get_data() on it.

Comment: remove this code `$order_data = $order->get_data();`